# Android XML Parsing(XmlPullParser) - cant retrieve text from XML

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Problem: XML parsing returns a null pointer exception, unable to retrieve the text from the program tag in xml. Stepping through code shows:
(This is from the debug statements as shown in code below)

```
err StartTag entry
err StartTag record
err Text 4
```

Line that calls parser (also the one that causes nullpointer, pail is a freshly created container):

```
pail = XmlParsee.parsee(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testprogramlist));
```

My XML File:

```
<entry>
    <record>
        <program>Program 1(English)</program>
    </record>
    <record>
        <program>Program 2(Mandarin)</program>
    </record>
</entry>
```

My parser (I tried both getText() and nextText(), both return the same issue):

```
public class XmlParsee {
// jealousy has invaded! Generic xml parser that returns a container
public static Container parsee(InputStream inputriver) {
    Container container = null;

    try {
        // get new parser object from factory
        XmlPullParser parsee = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        parsee.setInput(inputriver, null);

        int eventType = parsee.getEventType();
        // while xml still has more, we read.

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT: {
                    //these comments to be replaced with logging functions, if you desire
                    //wokay, we begin
                    container = new Container();
                    System.err.println("doc start");
                    break;
                }
                case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:{
                    //wokay, we end.
                    break;
                }
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:{
                    //new tag! first we get the tag's name
                    String tag = parsee.getName();
                    System.err.println("StartTag "+parsee.getName());
                    //then we check, individually, what the tag is to confirm content
                    //if <program>
                    if(tag.equalsIgnoreCase(Container.PROGRAM)){
                        System.err.println("Text "+parsee.TEXT);
                        //container.addProgramList(parsee.getText());
                    }
                    //if <>                     
                    break;
                }
            }
            //done with this line, next!
            eventType = parsee.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        container = null;
    }

    return container;
}
```

Any ideas? I've been banging my head at this since morning =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nextText() works for me;

```
    //System.err.println("Text "+parsee.TEXT);
    System.err.println("Text "+parsee.nextText());
```

the output:

```
...
09-13 14:51:22.035: W/System.err(12080): doc start
09-13 14:51:22.035: W/System.err(12080): StartTag entry
09-13 14:51:22.045: W/System.err(12080): StartTag record
09-13 14:51:22.065: W/System.err(12080): StartTag program
09-13 14:51:24.285: W/System.err(12080): Text Program 1(English)
09-13 14:56:57.505: W/System.err(12080): StartTag record
09-13 14:56:57.515: W/System.err(12080): StartTag program
09-13 14:56:58.075: W/System.err(12080): Text Program 2(Mandarin)
...
```

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Comment: Okay, my bad. Identified the wrong place that was erroneous.
Feeling rather silly now. Thanks!